On the norm of the unit element in a Banach algebra
In Serge Lang's Functional Analysis, when defining a Banach algebra, he states that "when there is a unit element, we shall assume that $|e| = 1$." He also notes that this is not always true in general, but we can always define a new norm to ensure this condition holds. This new norm appears in Exercise 5 of the same chapter:
$$
\|x\| = \sup_{y \neq 0} \frac{|x y|}{|y|}.$$
It’s straightforward to verify that this satisfies all the axioms of a norm and that $\|e\| = 1$. However, I cannot see how this remains a Banach algebra. It is clear that the space remains complete, since
$$
|x_m - x_n| \leq \|x_m - x_n\| |e| \leq |x_m - x_n||e|,$$
but I am unable to prove the sub-multiplicativity condition, i.e. $\|x z\| \leq \|x\| \|z\|$ for all $x, z$. This inequality feels like it should be obvious, but every approach I’ve tried seems to fall short.

The new norm is simply the operator norm of the left multiplication operator $L_x(y) = xy$ under the original norm $|\cdot|$. Multiplication of two elements becomes composition of multiplication operators corresponding to those two elements, from which sub-multiplicativity easily follows.

Ah, I didn’t realize this was simply the left multiplication operator. In that case, the standard proof of sub-multiplicativity for operator norms should apply, correct? Namely,
$$|x z| = \sup_{y \neq 0} \frac{|(x z) y|}{|y|} = \sup_{\substack{y \neq 0\ zy \neq 0}} \frac{|x(zy)|}{|zy|}\frac{|zy|}{|y|} \leq \sup_{y' \neq 0}\frac{|x y'|}{|y'|} \sup_{y \neq 0}\frac{|z y|}{|y|} = |x||z|.$$

@huh That is correct, yes.
